# Deadlock when app visibility changes

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to develop a continuous location tracking app and testing it on W10 phone. It runs fine on background when I hit Back or Windows button.

However, when the app is in foreground and I press power button, wait a while and then power on, the application is gone. The crash dump shows error 0xc0000194 "Possible deadlock condition".

So far I was only able to get this stack info:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x6
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x112
twinapi_appcore!PsmRegisterAppStateChangeNotification+0x2a4
twinapi_appcore!PsmRegisterAppStateChangeNotification+0x21f8
twinapi_appcore!PsmRegisterAppStateChangeNotification+0x2232
Windows_UI_Xaml+0x3777a8
Windows_UI_Xaml+0x37750e
0xbb067c
```

I noticed that when I hit Back or Windows key, *VisibilityChanged* occurs immediately. However when I press power off, this event is delayed, about 10 secs.

Could the deadlock be related to this? Is there any way to detect power button? I can stop doing UI updates when location is updated as soon as my app goes off screen, but need to know it asap, not delayed.
Thanks.